# Conditional React Navigation header button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to make a button appear in `headerRight` of the header bar in a React Navigation screen, but I cant seem to get it to work.

I want the start button (what is in `headerRight`) to show when `props.players.length > 1`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you give a more complete excerp of your code?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the same mechanics describe here for title: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#setting-the-header-title

Set a navigation params and use it on your navigationOptions.

In your case:

```
state = { players: 0 };

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerRight: navigation.getParam('players', 0) > 1 ? <YourHeaderButtonComponent /> : null ,
  };
};

addPlayer = () => {
    this.setState(({players}) => {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({players: players + 1})
        return {players: players + 1 }
    });
}

render {
    ...
    <Button onPress={this.addPlayer}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **nested navigation** for example a child bottomTabNavigator inside a parent stackNavigator please look att applying parent screen options based on child navigator's state see documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state)

For me the second option with Using navigation.setOptions worked with a child bottom tab navigator so I could change stackNavigator header options based on bottomTabNavigator page.